# Using vector and seq to rename dataframe

Tags: r, names

I have a .csv file with scanning spectroscopic data. Each run generates to types of data the wavelength and the absorption. the first line in the .csv looks like this Sample1,,220201_CBP21_WT,, giving me the name of the sample run as the name of the wavelength column when imported and nothing (ie the numbered position) for the absorbtion. I want to copy the name of the first column to the second and combine it with a string like "abs" for every other column.

tried to just give them same name with name and rename just as a starting point but couldn't get that to work either

```
df = data.frame(firstname = c(1,2,3),"1" = c(13,13,15), secondname = c(1,2,3), "2" = c(12,13,12))

oldnames = names(df)
names(df[seq(1,3,2)]) = oldnames[seq(2,4,2)]

#or
rename(df,df[seq(1,3,2)]) = oldnames[seq(2,4,2)])
```

So I want the names to df to be firstname, firstname, secondname, secondname at the very least idealy somthing like firstname, firstname_abs, secondname, secondname_abs

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you have 2 columns and you want to rename your second column to something like (first column)_(second column)

But in any case as general solution what you're probably looking for is `paste()` or `paste0()`
So it should be something like -

```
df$column = paste("text",df$column,sep = "separator")
```

OR

```
df$columnB = paste(df$columnA,df$columnB,sep = "separator")
```

`paste()` requires you set the separator or sets a space by default

You can use `paste0()` which doesn't have any separator requirement just joins as is

```
df$column = paste0("text","separator if required",df$column)
```

OR

```
df$columnB = paste(df$columnA,"separator if required",df$columnB)
```

Your question is slightly vague as to what sort of result you want exactly, maybe you can type out a sample of the input and output you expect. Then I can improve the answer.

Edit: Based on your comment you can do something like to rename every alternate columns the way you want -

Extract the column names:

```
temp_names = colnames(df)
```

Then change every alternate name in the list by pasting **_abs** to the one before it:

```
temp_names[c(seq(2,length(temp_names),2))] = paste0(temp_names[c(seq(1,length(temp_names),2)),"_abs"])
```

Then rename the columns:

```
colnames(df) = temp_names
```

Example Run:

```r
temp_names = c("test1","","test2","","test3","")
temp_names
[1] "test1" ""      "test2" ""      "test3" ""
temp_names[c(seq(2,length(temp_names),2))] = paste0(temp_names[c(seq(1,length(temp_names),2))],"_abs")
temp_names
[1] "test1"     "test1_abs" "test2"     "test2_abs" "test3"     "test3_abs"
```

Comment: I have a dataframe where everyodd numbered coloumn has the correct name and every even numberd coloumn has the wrong name. the coloumns contain data that are paired so the data in coloumn 1 coresponds with the data in coloumn 2. There are a lot fo coloumns so I some way to :
1. extract the original names
2. select the correct names from the odd numbered positions
3. rename all the even numbered coloumns with the odd numbered names (possibly with an aditional sufix)

currently the first 4 coloumns are named right, wrong, right2, wrong2.
I want the names to be right, right_abs, right2, aso

Comment: Ah I see! So you just need to change every alternate column name by adding "_abs". `paste0` will still work. But it'll be slightly more elaborate. I've edited the answer.

Comment: If this worked, could you please accept the answer. :)